# Collect configs from All apps, and run code after all apps are loaded (Django)

Tags: django, django-2.0, django-2.1

I want to be able to able to inject some configurations from each app, and then run some code after all apps are loaded to load a service with all the provided configurations from all apps. How do I go about implementing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more the intention of loading all the config from each app? IMO Django by default has an ability to centralize the configuration in the one particular main app inside the project, and of course, it's configurable by mean you can store the configuration outside the project, using env_vars for instance.

```
TWITTER_SECRET = os.getenv('TWITTER_SECRET')
```

Some reference might help:
[Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/)
[The Twelve-Factor APP](https://12factor.net/config)